# How do i install and setup open jdk from in ubuntu from snapcraft

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

### System

ubuntu 20.04 lts

> I'm just starting with ubuntu

### Installed

I have installed java from here https://snapcraft.io/openjdk

Command `sudo snap install openjdk`

> Installation was successfull

### Checked version

```js
rahul@rahul:~$ java -version

Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72, or
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless  # version 13.0.4+8-1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-14-jre-headless  # version 14.0.2+12-1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~20.04
```

### Checked for installation

```js
rahul@rahul:~$ sudo snap install openjdk
snap "openjdk" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

### How can i fix this?

Comment: what is the output of  `echo $PATH`?

Comment: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: check if java is listed in `sudo snap list` and then run `snap refresh openjdk`

Comment: I have installed it manually

Answer (score 3):

As it is written in [GitHub site](https://github.com/jgneff/openjdk#self-contained) of [openjdk](https://snapcraft.io/openjdk) in snapcraft, if you type `openjdk.java -version` you will get the version information